# Numerical integration with big errors

Tags: python, continuous-integration, integration

I'm trying to compute this integral, but the errors seems too high.

I tried changing the precision with `mp.mp.dps = 100` and `maxdegree= 3000` but without any good results.

Is it possible to compute such an integral ?

```
import mpmath as mp
A = 106.829
B = 2546.40
DD = 1000.0
mp.mp.dps = 100

nom = lambda oo, mm: (2 * mm - 1) * mm**( DD * mm) * (
              mp.exp( (2 * mm - 1) * A -  (mm/oo) * B)) /  (mp.gamma(mm) ** DD * oo ** (DD * mm) )

nomRes = mp.quad(nom,[0.5,3.0],[0.5,3.0], error = True, maxdegree= 3000)
```

I got the following error :

```
nomRes = (5.2385053e-792,5.1842e-792)
```

This error suggests that I can't trust the value obtained.

Answer (score 1):

You are raising things to power `DD*mm` which is huge. What do you expect to get?

Comment: even so, it's not possible? I have a research problem that need this solution

Comment: Looks öike some sort of overflow. Maybe use different units? Which equation is that?

Comment: I tried using mpmath to change the precision of the calculation. It's the optimum that a neural network can learn. I'm using as a benchmark.